# Why the latest versions are not updated in the npm remote repository?

Tags: reactjs, npm

We have an NPM repository configured in our Jfrog. We would like to ask why the latest versions are not updated in the npm remote repository, (e.g. react 18.6.4)?
As far as we know, the latest version was launched 14 days ago.

Comment: I am guessing the typo was unintentional. The latest react version is `16.8.6`.

Answer (score 0):

The syncing of dependencies in custom npm registries depends on how it is configured. Package updates might not be automatically synced. It may require a new fetch.

Try executing `npm install react`. That should make your remote registry verify if its local version is same as the latest version in its remote (`npmjs`). If not it will fetch the latest version, update as its local version, and provide the same to you.